# How to change Photoshop canvas orientation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, canvas, portrait

How do I change a canvas orientation from landscape to portrait and vice versa?

For instance: There is an option with artboard/page (in AI and PS / ID) to change the orientation, but what I want to do with canvas, does not exist.

** It's obvious that canvas size values exchange makes it possible, but it's a manual procedure. I need a more-automaton method.

*** I think it's scriptable by using "Canvas Size" feature. The script could replace the values of width and height with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If don't care about the crop, a simple script:

```
var doc = activeDocument;
var w = doc.width.as('px');
var h = doc.height.as('px');
var bottomLayer;

try {
    bottomLayer = doc.backgroundLayer;
    bottomLayer.isBackgroundLayer = false;
} catch(e) {}

doc.resizeCanvas(new UnitValue(h, 'px'), new UnitValue(w, 'px'));
```

It'll also make a BG layer non-BG layer.

Comment: Sorry for delayed "Thank you" comment! This script works very fine and is exactly what I need, and even maybe some body else's need too! It won't crop anything, I mean no pixels got cleared after canvas changed and all layers left untouched! Very Good Work... Thank you alot ;)

Comment: @RoozbehE You're welcome. Yes I think I wrote about the crop before I added the part where background layer is converted to a normal floating layer, so no cropping is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Canvas size, and merely swap the width and height numbers.

While it's possible to merely rotate an **image** that is quite different than rotating the **canvas**. I don't think there's any "quick flip" method for the canvas orientation.

Comment: For sure it's different that rotating image, and also when change orientation, it could drop some part of objects or image off the canvas. It's good to make a script that converts "Background Layer" to normal layer and then continue it's job.